# How to use export directive for Object.defineProperty?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2016

It's clear how to use the export statement with object or function:

```
export function take(source, n) {
         return source.slice(0, n);         
}
```

But what if i'd like to extend prototype using Object.defineProperty

```
Object.defineProperty(Enumerable.prototype, 'take', {
  value(n) {
    return [].concat(this).slice(0, n);
  },
});
```

How to use export in this case?

Comment: Instances of the `Enumerable` constructor will have that property in their prototype chain.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really have to export anything, but in other files where you want to use the extended prototype, you have to import the file where you did it.

```js
// enumerable.js
Object.defineProperty(Enumerable.prototype, 'take', {
  value(n) {
    return [].concat(this).slice(0, n);
  },
});
```

```js
// index.js
import * as enumerable from './enumerable.js'

console.log(Enumerable.prototype.take) // will be a function here
```

Comment: there is nothing exported from `enumerable.js` to import. I think the import is redundant?

Comment: Without the import, the JS engine won't load the `enumerable.js` file and therefore it doesn't know what changes are made to the prototype of `Enumerable`. This is why modifying prototypes is not recommended and we should rather extend the class.

Comment: If you're loading a file just for side-effects you don't need to name it, e.g. `import './enumerable.js';`